# ANDROID: MediaPlayer shows error (1, -19)

Tags: java, android, service

I'm working on a `Service` that plays a song picked from an `ArrayList`.
The problem comes when I use `prepare()` and `prepareAsync()`methods, so here's the code:

```
public class MusicService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener{
    private final static int DEF_VALUE = -1;
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<Song> mSongsList;
    private MediaPlayer mPlayer;
    private boolean isPlaying = false;
    private int mPosition;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        mContext = getApplicationContext();
        mSongsList = new ArrayList<Song>();
        mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        setMusicPlayer();
    }

    public void setMusicPlayer(){
        //Setting player properties
        mPlayer.setWakeMode(mContext, PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
        mPlayer.setAudioSessionId(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        int mCommand = intent.getIntExtra("CMD", DEF_VALUE);
        int mTrackSelected = intent.getIntExtra("TRACK_CLICKED", DEF_VALUE);

        /** SERVICE COMMANDS
         *  0 = SERVICE PERMISSIONS
         *  1 = PLAY_PAUSE
         *  2 = NEXT TRACK
         *  3 = PREV TRACK
         *  4 = SONG IN LIST
         */

        switch (mCommand){
            case 0:
                GetTracks mGetSongs = new GetTracks();
                mSongsList = mGetSongs.listAllSongs(mContext);
                Log.d("test size arrayList", ""+mSongsList.size());
                break;
            case 1:
                setPlayPause();
                break;
            case 2:
                skipNextTrack();
                break;
            case 3:
                skipPrevTrack();
                break;
            case 4:
                if(mTrackSelected != DEF_VALUE){
                    mPosition = mTrackSelected;
                    setSongToPlay(mPosition);
                }
                break;
            default:
                Log.d("error cmd", "You shouldn't be here!");
                break;
        }

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private void skipPrevTrack() {
        Log.d("method called:", "skipPrevTrack()");
        if(mPosition == 0){
            setSongToPlay(mPosition = mSongsList.size()-1);
        } else setSongToPlay(--mPosition);
        Log.d("test mPosition service", ""+mPosition);
    }

    private void skipNextTrack() {
        Log.d("method called:", "skipNextTrack()");
        if(mPosition == mSongsList.size()-1){
            setSongToPlay(mPosition = 0);
        } else setSongToPlay(++mPosition);
        Log.d("test mPosition service", ""+mPosition);
    }


    private void setSongToPlay(int pos) {
        Log.d("method called:", "setSongToPlay("+pos+")");
        startSong(mSongsList.get(pos).getSongUri());
    }
    private void startSong(Uri uri){

        try{
            mPlayer.reset();
            mPlayer.setDataSource(mContext, uri);
            mPlayer.prepareAsync();

            /** +++WORKS FINE WITH THIS CODE+++
             mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(mContext, uri);
             mPlayer.start();
             */

        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void setPlayPause() {
        Log.d("method called:", "setPlayPause()");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.start();
    }
}
```

LOG:

```
 12-19 16:12:18.325 4013-4013/sebbsoft.myApp D/method called:: setSongToPlay(3)
12-19 16:12:18.341 4013-4013/sebbsoft.myApp D/test song playing: Fiori del male ft. Sfera Ebbasta
12-19 16:12:18.363 4013-4013/sebbsoft.myApp D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
12-19 16:12:18.428 4013-4028/sebbsoft.myApp E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -19)
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: post the full stack trace

Comment: It only gives me the lines that i wrote in LOG

Comment: check last part of my answer it may help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally solved it! After a lot of trial & error!!
This is the line that causes it for me:

```
mMediaPlayer.setAudioSessionId(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

The API doc for setAudioSessionId doesn't indicate any alternative or any issue on still using it which made it hard to debug. But I saw setAudioStreamType just below it, which is deprecated and suggests [setAudioAttributes](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setAudioAttributes(android.media.AudioAttributes)) instead, w/c is added in API 21.

So I changed the above code to this:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        mMediaPlayer.setAudioAttributes(new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                .build());
} else {
        mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
}
```

And now it works!

By the way, as you can see, I checked only against version N (API 24) and above instead of from LOLLIPOP even though `setAudioAttributes` was added in API 21, because I only encounter this issue on Nougat devices, `setAudioSessionId` works up to Marshmallow devices for me so... don't wanna break anything that's already working.

I do hope someone would stop by and explain why this happens and what the error really means.

Hope this saves anyone days of headache :)

**EDIT:**
For anyone Googling around, I also changed the original `mMediaPlayer.setAudioSessionId` to `mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType`, as pointed out by *Eugen Pechanec*. See his comment and answer for details.
You would also want to change from checking against `Build.VERSION_CODES.N` to `Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP` with that.

Comment: I don't think you're using `setAudioSessionId` correctly. `setAudioAttributes` is available since Lollipop, but old version of that is `setAudioStreamType`. `setAudioSessionId` is supposed to be used with `AudioManager.generateAudioSessionId()` NOT with a stream type.

Comment: Woah! You're right! I got confused by those methods. Thanks for pointing that out! :)

Answer (score 2):

You're using `setAudioSessionId` incorrectly.

> The audio session ID is a **system wide unique identifier** for the audio stream played by this MediaPlayer instance.
>
> [...]
>
> When created, a **MediaPlayer instance automatically generates its own audio session ID**. However, **it is possible to force this player to be part of an already existing audio session** by calling this method. This method must be called before one of the overloaded `setDataSource` methods.

You would obtain an audio session ID by calling [`AudioManager.generateAudioSessionId()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#generateAudioSessionId()).

---

What you're probably looking for if you want to set the stream type is [`MediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setAudioStreamType(int)).

Newer API for this available since Android 5 is [`MediaPlayer.setAudioAttributes(AudioAttibutes)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setAudioAttributes(android.media.AudioAttributes)).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Uploading many diferent audios to a Mediaplayer.

after 15 times it stopped to work.

I just add release every time before upload a new audio in the same Mediaplayer and this worked for me!

no more Error (1, -19)

hope helps!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have too many `MediaPlayer` objects active at once.

Implement the `OnCompletionListener` and register it with your `MediaPlayer` instance.
`onCompletion` called when the end of a media source is reached during playback.

```
void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp){
   //Here you stop it.
   mp.stop();
   mPlayer.reset()
   //Reset the data source path to the new file
   mp.setDataSource(<uri>);
   mPlayer.prepare(); // or mPlayer.prepareAsync();
   // start the mediaplayer after the prepare has completed.
}
```

Release the `mediaplayer` instance once you are done playing all the files.

---

May be your listener only listen one time, then when it try to play the next one without prepared then it can crash.. try this too

add this -- > `mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);` in your `startSong()` method before your `prepareAsync`

Comment: I've just noticed that my code works fine on my personal phone with Android Marshmallow, but it still gives this error on a phone that I use for testing (a Galaxy S3 with a 7.1.1 rom)

Comment: may be you can try to n use `android:largeHeap="true" `to request a larger heap size and see in your menifest

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same problem, I solved it by adding the following code to release the player:

1- get Audio use Assets File

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
AssetFileDescriptor afd;  
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
         mediaPlayer.prepare();
          mediaPlayer.start();
        mp1.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.release();}; });
```

2- get Audio use res/raw folder.

```
mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(sound.this, R.raw.pan1);
mp1.start();
mp1.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.release();

    }; });
```

Comment: Didn't work for me - error in listener has gone, but some sounds were still skipped. Calling release() before creating new MediaPlayer solved the issue.